# Wireless network card in other slot

Tags: networking, network-adapter, pci-express

I got this [motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B85-G43.html). I want to buy a [wireless network card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007GMPZ0A), but the graphics card takes two mobo slots, and hides a PCI Ex1.0 slot (the bottom one).

Can I put a network card in the top PCI Ex1.0 slot ? Also, if I want to use the secondary blue (big) PCI Ex16 for that reason, will this reduce graphics card's speed by half ?

P.S. I read the manual but I don't understand what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put your PCI-E x1 card in the top slot on your motherboard. And using the other x16 slot will not effect your current graphics card. As stated on the website, the other x16 slot is 2.0 and will only run at x4 speed.

Comment: x4 speed referred only if I use two graphic cards as one? There is no problem if I use the slot for network card?

Comment: Your graphics card will work on x16 no matter what. The other slot, although it is a physical x16 slot is electrically a x4 slot so there will be no conflict. Your x1 card will not affect it either.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.